# How to call error_handler automatically?

Tags: php, api, rest

From my previous question I understand that isn't a good practice manage each exception with `try/catch` block, 'cause if I've hundred functions I should put hundred `try/catch` block. 
Now I noticed the [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function, if I've understand correctly (never used it), allow me to swith in a file or function all the error generated in the whole scripts. 
So instead of put `try catch` block this function should automatically intercept the error and call a function, is right? 
Now I already have a `Log` class that help me to write a stack trace in a file. This file is daily so I can see all system transaction in separated file.

My `Log` class is a SingleTon, so in each classes if I want write some trace in the log file I just need to do this:

```
Log::warning('some parameter here');
```

My goal is create an `error.php` file where all the error are switched in the `Log::warning('...');`.
 I think that this `set_error_handler` should be placed in the system core. As I said I never worked with it, someone could help me to achieve this with a bit example? I'll be glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_error_handler` is used to handle errors in a script not exceptions.

If you want to catch all exceptions from your application to apply the same process you have to call `set_exception_handler` [PHPDoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).
This function takes a callable in argument, so your handler must be defined in another function.

The main difference between this function and a `try catch` block is that

> Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.

It's a also good practice to keep existing exception handlers possibly introduce by an included lib.
You can create a class to do this

```
class ErrorHandler
{
    private $previousExceptionHandler;

    public function registerExceptionHandler($callPrevious = true)
    {
        $prev = set_exception_handler(array($this, 'handleException'));
        if ($callPrevious && $prev) {
            $this->previousExceptionHandler = $prev;
        }
    }
    public function handleException(\Exception $e)
    {
         // DO YOUR STUFF

        if ($this->previousExceptionHandler) {
            call_user_func($this->previousExceptionHandler, $e);
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it

```
$errorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
$errorHandler->registerExceptionHandler();
```

There are some good libs to do that and more, especially if you want to catch your exceptions for logging purpose. You can try the excellent [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) lib wihich is widely used, and its `ErrorHandler` class

Comment: the condition `if($this->_prevExceptionHandler)` isn't fired.. the value is ever `false` why?